# How do I add shapes from an Array to Stage Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to create an array of squares and then add them to the stage in a 6x12 grid and later on be able to change their colours. I have managed to create an array of arrays and store the squares, but I am at a loss for how to now add them to the stage in a grid. I'm a new programmer so I apologize in advance if I have not formatted my code correctly. THank you for your time.

public class Main extends Sprite
    {

```
    public function Main():void
    {
        stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
        stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
        stage.addEventListener(Event.DEACTIVATE, deactivate);

        // touch or gesture?
        Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;

        //array of arrays
        var pixelArray:Array = [row1, row2, row3, row4, row5, row6, row7, row8, row9, row10, row11, row12]

        // Row arrays
        var row1:Array = [];
        var row2:Array = [];
        var row3:Array = [];
        var row4:Array = [];
        var row5:Array = [];
        var row6:Array = [];
        var row7:Array = [];
        var row8:Array = [];
        var row9:Array = [];
        var row10:Array = [];
        var row11:Array = [];
        var row12:Array = [];

        for (var i:int = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {

            // "Pixel"
            var pixel:Shape = new Shape; // initializing the variable 
            pixel.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0x000000, 1);
            pixel.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000); // fill colour
            pixel.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 30, 30); // (x spacing, y spacing, width, height)
            pixel.graphics.endFill(); // end of fill
            //addChild(pixel); // adds to stage, all shapes will be in same place?

            row1.push(pixel);
            row2.push(pixel);
            row3.push(pixel);
            row4.push(pixel);
            row5.push(pixel);
            row6.push(pixel);
            row7.push(pixel);
            row8.push(pixel);
            row9.push(pixel);
            row10.push(pixel);
            row11.push(pixel);
            row12.push(pixel);


        }
        addChild(pixelArray [1][1]); //tried to add just one square to stage, I think syntax is wrong here

    }

    private function deactivate(e:Event):void
    {
        // make sure the app behaves well (or exits) when in background
        //NativeApplication.nativeApplication.exit();
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You're placing one and the same `pixel` into each of the rows. To make more pixels, you need to create a pixel per row per column. To avoid copypaste, you can make a function that will return a ready-made `Shape` object, and you will call that in all of your `rowX.push()` statements. Like this:

```
function makePixel(fillColor:int=0xff0000):Shape {
    var pixel:Shape=new Shape();
    pixel.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0x000000, 1);
    pixel.graphics.beginFill(fillColor); // fill colour
    pixel.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 30, 30); // (x spacing, y spacing, width, height)
    pixel.graphics.endFill(); // end of fill
    return pixel;
}
row1.push(makePixel());
row2.push(makePixel());
// etc
```